# How was “add application for mailto links” enabled in Firefox?

Tags: webmail

Every time I log on to my webmail I see a bar like on image below. I don't want to add this as an application and it is pretty annoying to close this every time. How can I disable it permanently?

The bar says:

> Add o2 Poczta (poczta.o2.pl) as an application for mailto links? [Add
>   Application] x

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/itY4O.jpg

I tried to use Firebug to see what causes this bar to appear but with no luck. Anyone help?
I think there might me something on server side that makes Firefox behave in this way.
How did they do that?

url to webmail is http://poczta.o2.pl

Comment: Flagging for migration. Belongs at SO.

Comment: Please can we have the question here and not via links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by [registering a protocol handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Web-based_protocol_handlers#Registering). From that page:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto",
                              "https://www.example.com/?uri=%s",
                              "Example Mail");
```

The site would just have to run a similar snippet at an appropriate moment(login, in your case).

Comment: How can I block that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/994658 , there's a suggestion to set `network.protocol-handler.external.mailto` to `true`. That makes no sense, and it is the default setting. However, after changing it to **false** and reloading the page ( https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox ), the notification is gone.

1. Enter `about:config` in the address bar.
2. Filter on `network.protocol-handler.external.mailto`and set it to `false`.
3. Reload your online e-mail service page.